# How can upgrade gedit 2.30.4 to version 3?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, gedit

I want to use some plugins available for v3 of gedit.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, you can't upgrade without recompiling or upgrading all of its dependencies, and that's because of the transition from Gnome2 to Gnome3 that took place in Ubuntu 11.10.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/gedit